# Find domain $\;g(x)= \sqrt{x^2-9}\;$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Okay  $g(x)=  \sqrt{x^2-9}$

thus, $x^2 -9 \ge 0$

equals $x \ge +3$  and $x \ge -3$

thus the domains should be $[3,+\infty) \cup [-3,\infty)$ how come the answer key in my book is stating  $(−\infty, −3] \cup[3,\infty)$.

Comment: It is $x\le -3$, not $x\ge -3$.

Comment: why has the sign changed? You did not divide.

Comment: I just fixed it. Yes that is what I mean.

Comment: @user137452, it is $$x^2-9\ge 0\iff x^2\ge 9\iff |x|\ge 3\iff x\le -3\;\;or\;\;x\ge 3\; $$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Domain and Range of f(x)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491905/domain-and-range-of-fx)

Comment: Timbuc. so what you are telling me that x is an absolute value now? That is not the way I was taught to find the domain for square roots. Can you explain in my train of thought?

Comment: @user137452, read my answer below as it is a little long for a comment

Comment: @Jeremy That explanation is convoluted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get to the point of $x^{2} - 9 \geq 0$, you are definitely allowed to add $9$ to both sides to get $x^{2} \geq 9$, but you are **not** allowed to then take the square root of both sides.

When you have inequalities (like $< , \le, >, \ge$), you can't take the square root of both sides like you can when you have an equality ($=$).

If we have $x^{2} - 9 = 0$, then you know how to solve this.  First add $9$ to both sides and then take the square root of both sides, and get $x = 3$ and $x = -3$ as solutions.

But if you can't take the square root of both sides in $x^{2} \geq 9$, then how the heck do you solve it?? Well, there is a special technique we can use for inequalities.  First, don't add $9$ to both sides.  Instead, keep it as $x^{2} - 9 \geq 0$.

Now, you should notice that $x^{2} - 9$ is the difference of squares.  I can rewrite it as $x^{2} - 3^{2}$ since $3^{2} = 9$.  And you should know how to factor the difference of squares.  $x^{2} - a^{2}$ becomes $(x - a)(x + a)$.  So, that means we can rewrite $x^{2} - 9$ as $(x - 3)(x + 3)$.

Great, so since we wanted to solve $x^{2} - 9 \geq 0$, this becomes $(x - 3)(x + 3) \geq 0$.  Now what?

Well, now you need to find which values of $x$ make $(x - 3)(x + 3)$ *greater than or equal to* $0$.  Here is a trick that will always help you solve this:  Draw a number line and mark it with the numbers that make the factors on the left hand size $0$.  So $3$ makes $x-3$ equal to $0$, and $-3$ makes $x + 3$ equal to $0$, so I will draw a number line and mark it with $3$ and $-3$.

------------|---------------|-----------

...............-3....................3...............

Now, you need to pick test points.  Pick a number less than $-3$, like $-4$, and plug it into $(x - 3)(x + 3)$.  If after you simplify you get something greater than or equal to $0$, then part of our solution will be $(-\infty, -3)$.  If you get something negative, then we don't want $(-\infty, -3)$ in our solution.

Now you must test the marking $-3$.  Plug it into $(x - 3)(x + 3)$ and you will get $0$.  But $0$ is greater than or equal to $0$, so we want to include $-3$ in our solution.

Now pick an easy number between $-3$ and $3$ (like $0$), and plug it into $(x - 3)(x + 3)$.  Again, if we get something greater than or equal to $0$, we will want to include the interval $(-3,3)$ in our solution.  If we get something negative, we don't want this interval to be in our solution.

Now test the number $3$.  Plug it into $(x - 3)(x + 3)$ and you will get $0$.  But $0$ is greater than or equal to $0$, so we want to include $3$ in our solution.

Finally, pick a number greater than $3$ (like $4$), and plug it into $(x - 3)(x + 3)$.  Again, if we get something greater than or equal to $0$, we will want to include the interval $(3, \infty)$ in our solution.  If we get something negative, we don't want this interval to be in our solution.

So, after doing all of that, you should find that the final answer is $(-\infty, -3] \cup [3, \infty)$.

Comment: Thanks so much for a great explanation and for putting it altogether. I totally forgot that one needs to find test points for non-linear equations.

Comment: @user137452 You're welcome! :)

Comment: If you take the square root of both sides of the inequality $x^2 \geq 9$, you obtain $|x| \geq 3$, which has solution $x \geq 3$ or $x \leq -3$, which yields the domain $D_f = (-\infty, -3] \cup [3, \infty)$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig This requires that you understand that $\sqrt{x^{2}} = |x|$, which is something that isn't often taught to (or understood/retained by) precalculus students, at least not from what I've seen (I am in the US).  Usually, factoring the left hand side and using test points is the method of solving this problem that is taught to students.

Comment: I am aware of that.  Your solution is both valid and useful.  I was responding to your statement that you cannot take the square root of both sides of the inequality $x^2 \geq 9$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, and I'm telling you that telling a student at that level, "You can take the square root of both sides of the inequality," would in the majority of cases cause them to say $x^{2} \geq 9 \implies x \geq \pm 3$.  Sometimes we have to tell white lies to students until they become more mature in the subject.  Besides, saying "you can't take the square root of both sides" is accurate, because I am referring to the method of taking square roots that *they* are familiar with.  I'm personally completely OK with telling harmless white lies to get a point across.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig P.S. I hope I did not sound rude in my last comment.  I completely respect your point that actually, we do "take the square root of both sides" but in a particular way.  You are completely right, and I hope I didn't offend you.

Comment: Lies, white or black, are not good politics when trying to teach science, in my opinion. Writing "you are **not** allowed to take square roots" is a blatant lie, white or any other color, and should be deleted. And any student deducing that taking square roots in $\;x^2\ge 9\;$ would lead to $\;x\ge \pm 3\;$ should better put his brains to work and/or demmand from his teachers to be well taught.

Comment: @Timbuc I respect your opinion, and I agree with you to an extent.  I am not sure if you are from the US or not, but my opinion comes from the fact that I was educated in the US.  Here, we are not taught math in elementary school, or high school, or even in the beginning Calculus classes, by learning, for example, a rigorous construction of the real line, or what a group is in Algebra, etc.  From what I have observed, I think we try to teach students without worrying if they understand the underlying intricacies at work, because they will understand those intricacies...

Comment: @Timbuc ...when they reach a higher level of mathematical maturity.  If we start teaching them about the all of the intricacies, then we risk confusing them.  The purpose of "white lies", in my opinion, is to help get the student from knowing nothing about math to knowing enough about math to work out the intricacies on their own.  For most people, there is a bridge between not knowing any math, and truly understanding math.  This bridge must be crossed, and I personally think the best way to help students cross that bridge is by not focusing on the underlying mechanisms at play and instead...

Comment: @Timbuc ...teach them how to solve problems.  Once they are able to solve the problems we teach them to solve, we can then return to explaining all of the underlying concepts.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following argument:

$$x^2-9=(x-3)(x+3)\ge 0\iff x\le -3\;\;\text{or}\;\;x\ge 3$$

You can see the above easily and geometrically: the function $\;f(x)=x^2-9\;$ is a parabolla opening upwards, and if you draw it it is non-negative exactly when $\;x\le -3\;$ or $\;x\ge 3\;$ .

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{x^2 - 9} \text{ exists} &\implies x^2-9 \ge 0\\&\implies (x+3)(x-3) \ge 0 \\&\implies (x-3), (x+3) \text{ both are non-negative OR } (x-3),(x+3) \text{both are non-positive} \end{align}$$

**case 1**
Now, $(x-3)(x+3)$ both are non-negative when $x-3 \ge 0$ and $x+3 \ge 0 \implies x \ge -3 $ and $x \ge 3 \implies x \ge 3$.

**case 2**
Now, $(x-3)(x+3)$ both are non-positive when $x-3 \le 0$ and $x+3 \le 0 \implies x \le -3 $ and $x \le 3 \implies x \le -3$.

Answer (score 1):

it must be $(x-3)(x+3)\geq 0$ and this means $x\geq 3$ or $x\le -3$.

Comment: Why are you guys changing the direction of the inequality?

Comment: The inequality is only satisfied if both terms have the same sign.  If $x \geq 3$, then both $x - 3 \geq 0$ and $x + 3 \geq 0$, so the product $(x + 3)(x - 3) \geq 0$.  If $x \leq -3$, then both $x - 3 \leq 0$ and $x + 3 \leq 0$, so $(x + 3)(x - 3) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

So we have that $$(x-3)(x+3)\geq0$$ Now this happens when either both $x-3$ and $x+3$ are positive or both are negative.Now solving $$x-3\geq0\land x+3\geq 0\implies x\geq 3\land x\geq -3\\x-3\leq0\land x+3\leq0\implies x\leq3\land x\leq-3$$
Now the first solution is $x\geq3$ and the second is $x\leq-3$

Comment: I'm not trying to sound rude, because you were very nice to take the time and try to help this user out, but do you really think someone at the precalculus level will understand the symbol you've written above for "and"?  Also, do you think they will understand the "implies" symbol?  You have to write an appropriate solution for the audience you're given.

Comment: @user46944, that may be almost impossible to achieve since there's no place in this site where people writes down what his mathematics level is.

Comment: @user46944 We've learned logic just before functions domain and such so I assume he knows the symbols,other than that he should know them because they are widely used in work books(some).Anyway my thought is that in math you must find yourself the path to understand some things,if you're getting handed all the info in most cases you don't understand it your way and you forget it soon,but if you've figured something on your own that is most likely in your head for many years.

Comment: @kingW3 I completely agree with you that when we figure things out on our own, we remember it for a very long time.  But I think it is very dangerous to talk about mathematics without worrying first if the audience will understand what you are saying.  I see this happen every day, and it bothers me because things don't have to be this way.  I am not suggesting you hand all of the information to the student on a silver platter.  But a failure to tailor the math you talk about to the specific audience you are talking to will accomplish nothing and only waste everyone's time.